# При вызове CLR функции выходит ошибка

Tags: sql-server, clr

Здравствуйте!
Ни как не могу понять из-за чего происходит эта ошибка при вызове clr функции:

```
Failed to create AppDomain "DBName.dbo[runtime].64". 
Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку "System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" или один из зависимых от них компонентов. Недостаточно памяти для обработки команды. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80070008)
```

может кто знает из-за чего?
спасибо!!!

Comment: всё работало отлично сегодня запускаю скрипт и такая ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл [решение](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/425178/failed-to-create-appdomain-while-create-clr-assembly-from-binary-source) перезагрузил сервис и всё заработало!!!